# Regarding Excel object

Tags: ado.net

i am using ADO.Net oledb for inserting and fetching data from Excel database. I want to make first column in the excel sheet to bold and i want to add comments. I am achieving this thru Interop.Excel Application class.

i dont want to use interop. is there anyway to achieve through ADO.net query itself ? or some other way? My application is c# windows application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way through ADO.NET, any more than there is of making a SQL Server column bold. ADO.NET treats Excel as a data source - formatting is something quite different and requires knowledge of the Excel spreadsheet format, such as you'd get via Interop. There are probably other libraries you can use if you search...